# how to hide UIActivityIndicatorView in another view controller in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in second view controller and when user select the button in the first view the `Json` will start But in the same time the app will run second `viewcontroller` with `UIActivityIndicatorView` animating I want when the `Json` in the first `viewcontroller` has finished stop `UIActivityIndicatorView` in the second view controller (Simply I want stop and hide `UIActivityIndicatorView` in another `viewcontroller`)

here is the codes of the first view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)!
    selectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    selectedCell.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    print("Chat Subject Has Benn Selected!")
    let selectedItem = indexPath.row
    print(selectedItem)


    chatViewController.selectedChat = selectedItem
    ///////////////////////Start Chat
    print(EmailSignInViewController.id)    

     ////////////////////// Get chat Page

     let urlPath3: String = "http://example/api?api_token=\(EmailSignInViewController.api_token)&id=\(EmailSignInViewController.id[selectedItem])"


     print(urlPath3)
     let url3: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath3)!
     let request3: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url3 as URL)

     request3.httpMethod = "GET"


     let queue3:OperationQueue = OperationQueue()

     NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request3 as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) {(response, data, error) in


        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url3 as URL)
            print(NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

     do {

     if let jsonResult3 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? Array<Any> {

     for item in jsonResult3 {
     print("item")
     print(item)

     if let dict = item as?  NSDictionary {
     if let type = dict.value(forKey: "type"){
     chatViewController.type.append(type as! Int)

     print("type")
     print("\([type])")

        chattingViewController.checklist.append(type as! Int)

     }

     if let text = dict.value(forKey: "text"){

     chatViewController.text.append(text as!String)


        chattingViewController.list.append(text as!String)
     print("text")
       print("\([text])")


     }
        if let created_at = dict.value(forKey: "created_at"){

                self.created.append(created_at as!String)


            print("created_at")
            print("\([created_at])")
            print("\([created_at])")


        }



     }
     }

         print(jsonResult3)

     print("ASynchronous\(jsonResult3)")
        chatViewController.created_at = self.created

        print("chat Page")

     }
     } catch let error as NSError {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
     }

          self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatting", sender: nil)

     }
```

as you see in my codes when `Json` Start the user will move to the second `viewcontroller` and the `UIActivityIndicatorView` will start animating and show and I want in the last line of `Json` Stop the animating and hide that
and here is second view controllers necessary codes

```
@IBOutlet weak var chattingWaiting: UIActivityIndicatorView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    chattingWaiting.startAnimating()
    chattingWaiting.isHidden = false

 }
```

Comment: If you are adding your second viewController as a child to first viewController then you can dismiss UIActivityIndicatorView of second viewController by [child.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

Comment: how can I do that? please help me

Comment: Please add some code to help you better.

Comment: OK I added codes of the first view controllers

Answer (score 0):

Update :: Real problem you have is you are adding `UIActivityIndicator` into `viewDidLoad()` method of your second view controller after navigation happens.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.startAnimating() //Add here
    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)!
    selectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    selectedCell.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    print("Chat Subject Has Benn Selected!")
    let selectedItem = indexPath.row
    print(selectedItem)


    chatViewController.selectedChat = selectedItem
    ///////////////////////Start Chat
    print(EmailSignInViewController.id)    

     ////////////////////// Get chat Page

     let urlPath3: String = "http://example/api?api_token=\(EmailSignInViewController.api_token)&id=\(EmailSignInViewController.id[selectedItem])"


     print(urlPath3)
     let url3: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath3)!
     let request3: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url3 as URL)

     request3.httpMethod = "GET"


     let queue3:OperationQueue = OperationQueue()

     NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request3 as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) {(response, data, error) in


        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url3 as URL)
            print(NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

     do {

     if let jsonResult3 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? Array<Any> {

     for item in jsonResult3 {
     print("item")
     print(item)

     if let dict = item as?  NSDictionary {
     if let type = dict.value(forKey: "type"){
     chatViewController.type.append(type as! Int)

     print("type")
     print("\([type])")

        chattingViewController.checklist.append(type as! Int)

     }

     if let text = dict.value(forKey: "text"){

     chatViewController.text.append(text as!String)


        chattingViewController.list.append(text as!String)
     print("text")
       print("\([text])")


     }
        if let created_at = dict.value(forKey: "created_at"){

                self.created.append(created_at as!String)


            print("created_at")
            print("\([created_at])")
            print("\([created_at])")


        }



     }
     }

         print(jsonResult3)

     print("ASynchronous\(jsonResult3)")
        chatViewController.created_at = self.created

        print("chat Page")

     }
     } catch let error as NSError {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
     }
          self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating() //Removed here
          self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatting", sender: nil)

     }
```

And also remove these 2 lines from your second view controller.

```
chattingWaiting.startAnimating()
chattingWaiting.isHidden = false
```

Comment: look like many chat apps like viber or whatsapp or ... I want when user select the chat son start because of the speed is very important and after that when Json complete the UIActivityIndicatorView stops and hide

Comment: That was just an advise to follow best practises, but you can dismiss activityIndicator by the code added above but if you are adding activityIndicator to parentView then use self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

Comment: ok so how can I add that ? Just drag that in story board to the first view controller codes or not?

Comment: You just need to add following line chatViewController.activityIndicator.stopAnimating() or self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating() depending on the parent view of activityIndicator

Comment: look my second view controller named chattingViewController and first one is chatViewController

Comment: Try chattingViewController.activityIndicator.stopAnimating() or self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating() and it should work.

Comment: Show some more code about how are you adding activityIndicator to your view.

Comment: as I said I want to get data in the first view controller but thanks for helping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150695/discussion-between-paras-gorasiya-and-saeed-rahmatolahi).